# chd=t truncate data to 100

Tags: graph, parameters, google-visualization, image-charts

I've read all of the documentation, and I can't seem to figure this one out.  I have the following URL for an image chart, however it caps the data at 100 for some reason.  I've been going crazy trying to figure out what that is.

https://image-charts.com/chart?chco=167DB3&chd=t:62,102,154,145,153,212,215,171,184,148,103,90,62,27,33,28,32,38,22,11,10,13,13,20&chm=B,0D4564,0,0,0&chma=0,0,20,10&chs=900x400&cht=lc&chxl=0:|7AM|8AM|9AM|10AM|11AM|12PM|1PM|2PM|3PM|4PM|5PM|6PM|7PM|8PM|9PM|10PM|11PM|12AM|1AM|2AM|3AM|4AM|5AM|6AM&chxt=x,y&chtt=Calls+By+Hour&chxr=1,0,200

Answer (score 1):

`chd=t:` (coming from Google Image Charts format) limits data to 100. See the first line of [our documentation here](https://documentation.image-charts.com/reference/data-format/#basic-text-format).

> Basic text-formatted data lets you specify floating point values from 0—100, inclusive, as numbers. Values below zero are marked as missing; values above 100 are truncated to 100.

But the good news, we did not stop at being a drop-in-replacement for Google Image Charts....... We've improved it!

Use our [Awesome Text format](https://documentation.image-charts.com/reference/data-format/#awesome-text-format) instead, change `chd=t:` to `chd=a:` and you are done!

## with `chd=t:`

[image]

```
https://image-charts.com/chart?chco=167DB3&chd=t:62,102,154,145,153,212,215,171,184,148,103,90,62,27,33,28,32,38,22,11,10,13,13,20&chm=B,0D4564,0,0,0&chma=0,0,20,10&chs=900x400&cht=lc&chxl=0:|7AM|8AM|9AM|10AM|11AM|12PM|1PM|2PM|3PM|4PM|5PM|6PM|7PM|8PM|9PM|10PM|11PM|12AM|1AM|2AM|3AM|4AM|5AM|6AM&chxt=x,y&chtt=Calls+By+Hour&chxr=1,0,200
```

## with `chd=a:`

[image]

```
https://image-charts.com/chart?chco=167DB3&chd=a:62,102,154,145,153,212,215,171,184,148,103,90,62,27,33,28,32,38,22,11,10,13,13,20&chm=B,0D4564,0,0,0&chma=0,0,20,10&chs=900x400&cht=lc&chxl=0:|7AM|8AM|9AM|10AM|11AM|12PM|1PM|2PM|3PM|4PM|5PM|6PM|7PM|8PM|9PM|10PM|11PM|12AM|1AM|2AM|3AM|4AM|5AM|6AM&chxt=x,y&chtt=Calls+By+Hour&chxr=1,0,200
```

[Edit this chart](https://editor.image-charts.com/chart?chco=167DB3&chd=a:62,102,154,145,153,212,215,171,184,148,103,90,62,27,33,28,32,38,22,11,10,13,13,20&chm=B,0D4564,0,0,0&chma=0,0,20,10&chs=900x400&cht=lc&chxl=0:|7AM|8AM|9AM|10AM|11AM|12PM|1PM|2PM|3PM|4PM|5PM|6PM|7PM|8PM|9PM|10PM|11PM|12AM|1AM|2AM|3AM|4AM|5AM|6AM&chxt=x,y&chtt=Calls+By+Hour&chxr=1,0,200)